# Separate numeric values and character values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

A table contains both numeric and character values in a column. The numeric values and character values need to be separated in different columns

| Col1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| A |
| B |
| C |

The output needs to be

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

Comment: SQL the language and SQL tables are _relational_ things.  How do we know that 1 pairs with A, 2 with B, etc. ?

Comment: The numbers go serially and so do characters as present in table

Comment: Do the numeric values ever have `+` or `-` signs?  Are they always single digits?  Do they ever have decimal places `.`?  Can they ever be formatted with `,` or other characters?  Is scientific notation ever used?  Are there ever rogue white space characters?

Comment: _"The numbers go serially and so do characters as present in table"_   Not without an appropriate ORDER BY clause, they don't.  I can understand that your _logic_ is that the character 'A' will pair with the character '1', but you need to clearly understand that in a relational database, rows are like balls in a basket. There is no inherent order. Without an ORDER BY, the exact same SELECT can very well return the exact same rows in a different order at different times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when regexp_like(col1, '^[0-9]*$') then col1 end),
       max(case when not regexp_like(col1, '^[0-9]*$') then col1 end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when regexp_like(col1, '^[0-9]*$') then 1 else 0 end)
                                order by col1
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

You cold simplify this a bit using a lateral join:

```
select max(case when is_number = 1 then col1 end),
       max(case when is_number = 0 then col1 end)
from (select t.*, x.is_number
             row_number() over (partition by x.is_number
                                order by col1
                               ) as seqnum
      from t cross join lateral
           (select (case when regexp_like(col1, '^[0-9]*$') then 1 else 0 end) as is_number
            from dual
           ) x
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` with a self join:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, REGEXP_LIKE(Col1, '^[[:digit:]]+$') AS is_number,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REGEXP_LIKE(Col1, '^[[:digit:]]+$') ORDER BY Col1) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT t1.Col1, t2.Col1
FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.rn = t1.rn
WHERE t1.is_number AND NOT t2.is_number
ORDER BY t1.rn;
```